# Long term effects of various constipation treatments?

Tags: medicine

Okay, so I think constipation *might* be relevant in this site because it's sort of related to nutrition, but..

One of the treatments to get rid of constipation is by using laxatives. However, I've heard that long-term uses of them are not desired, and can have detrimental effects.

What about suppositories? From what I've heard, they just soften up the stool on the spot, so would it be fair to assume that there's not much to worry about in terms of long-term effects?

Comment: Nutrition not related to exercise if off topic according to the [FAQ].

Answer (score 2):

Long-term use of any type of constipation treatment (suppositories/laxatives) can be detrimental because they reduce the amount of nutrients absorbed by the body.

One recommendation to counteract constipation is to increase the amount of fiber in your diet. Naturally occurring fiber is best - fruits, whole grains, vegetables, etc - while chemically produced fiber can cause bloating.

Another recommendation is to reduce the amount of constipation-causing foods in your diet. Cheeses, heavily-processed foods, fast foods, saturated fats all contribute to constipation.

The third fix is to get moving - stand and walk more during the day instead of sitting. Add some stretching and exercise to your daily routine.